# jQuery bind event doesn't consistently make CSS changes in UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the function below to change the some of the CSS/HTML structure of a page when the default tab of jQuery Tabs is selected. Problem is that it isn't "dynamic," and by that I mean it only fires the CSS in the function - the display:none on two selectors and the width on #wrapper - after another tab is clicked and then the default tab is clicked. And when other tabs are clicked, the CSS is not restored to the original state.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs2V/33/

How can I make this fire when the default tab is loaded on page load and also return the CSS when other tabs are clicked? Is there a better way to make markup changes as determined by the active tab?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs();

$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { 
      switch (ui.index){
        case 0: 
            $('#col2, #footer').css('display', 'none');
            $('#wrapper').css('width', '700px');
    break;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't have duplicate IDs across the different tabs, right?

Comment: @karim79: #col1 and #footer are outside of the tab structure and are not dupes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell it to revert back to original CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
        //your original css goes here such as $('#wrapper').css('width', '500px');
        If(ui.index == 0) {
            $('#col2, #footer').css('display', 'none');
            $('#wrapper').css('width', '700px');
        }
    });
```

On tabshow the function will first revert back to original CSS then checks if index 0 is clicked, CSS will change. Otherwise original CSS will not be altered.

Comment: Or he could use a `default` case in the switch statement.

Comment: I know, it was more to point it out rather than a critique of your answer (I plus one'd you).

Comment: @Hussein: Thanks, but the "if" breaks the tab init. And what happens when #col1 and #footer have more than one CSS attr that needs to be reset?

Comment: @songdogtech I updated the code, check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs2V/34/

Comment: Ah, that works great now. Don't know what I was doing wrong. But one issue: with the default tab set to 0 and on initial page load, I still see the display:none CSS. But if I switch to another tab and then back to default, the display:none CSS is hidden. Somehow, the CSS needs to be initialized on first page load.

Comment: @songdogtech `#col2, #footer` will be hidden initially and when index 0 is clicked on, otherwise they both show. Isn't this what you want.

Comment: Yes, that works fine. But when the complete webpage with tabs is first loaded, #col2, #footer are not hidden. But they will hide after another tab is clicked and then the 0 tab is clicked.

Comment: @songdogtech In the jsfiddle example i provided, they are hidden when page first loads. Are you not seeing that??

Comment: @Hussein: jsfiddle works, my own website didn't. Until I figured out that I needed to do - I had to put the display:none CSS into another doc ready call to hide upon first load on my website. So now it works fine, thanks. One more question: is it possible to animate the CSS change?

Comment: @songdogtech On your site also make sure you adjust the CSS as i have it in jsfiddle.